# The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera, photo-gallery

Getting this error but what not getting is when the both the keys for camera and gallery as well added in plist why this error and crash coming up. Please guide if something new has been introduced related to this in iOS 13 and swift 5. Below is the attachment of plist.

[image]

Comment: what is error ??

Comment: please provide error

Comment: i got,  i added permission for file rather than camera by mistake. I will delete this question

Answer (score 0):

In order to get access you have to add both of them , While the gallery gives you access to select an image you should also give camera access . Add the following Key

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

Comment: wrong question, please delete your answer i added permission for file rather than camera by mistake. I will delete this question